# javascript undefine keyword prefix with a string

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, concatenation, undefined

i try to reverse a string by finding the lenght first, using for-loop and den loops throught the range from the lenght to zero and concat it with other variable in order to store it in a reverse order, but i always get undefined prefix to it.

code -

```
function reverse1(str) {
  let len = 0;
  for (let i in str) {
    len += 1;
  }
  var r = "";
  for (var i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
    r += str[i];
  }
  return r;
}
console.log(reverse1("hello"));
```

output- undefinedolleh

How to get rid of this undefined keyword which get prefix in the reverse string

Comment: "*finding the lenght*" - don't "find" it by counting, just access `str.length`! And [don't use `for…in` enumerations on indexed structures!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: Just trying to avoid any kind of builtin function or method.

Comment: It's neither a function nor a method, it's just a basic property of strings. Just like `str[i]` is. But you cannot avoid all builtins, you need something to build your program from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Are assigning i in for loop with string length , it should be start from len-1

```
for (var i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: silly mistake i have made, thanks a lot . This was exactly wat am looking for

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe there is an easier way to do this, if that what are you going for.

```
const str = 'Hello World';
const reversed = str .split('').reverse().join('')
console.log(reversed); // dlroW olleH
```

Comment: Yes ofcourse, just curious if it can be done without any kind of builtin functions or method